# Adding # & search sign to TableIndex in UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, indexing

In iPhone native Phone book - there is a search character at the top & # character at the bottom.

I want to add both of that character in my table Index.

Currently I have implemented following code.

```
atoz=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for(int i=0;i<26;i++){
        [atoz addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",i+65]];
    }


- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return atoz;
}
```

How to have # character & search symbol in my UITableView?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to tackle this is to make use of the tools the framework provides. In this case, you want to use [UILocalizedIndexedCollation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalizedIndexedCollation_Class/UILocalizedIndexedCollation.html) (developer link).

I also have a decorator for this class that is designed to insert the {{search}} icon for you and handle the offsets. It is a like-for-like drop-in replacement for UILocalizedIndexedCollation.

I've posted a more in-depth description of how to use this [on my blog](http://lukeredpath.co.uk/blog/using-uilocalizedindexedcollation-with-searchable-table-views.html). The decorator is available [here](http://gist.github.com/305676) (Gist).

The basic idea is to group your collection into an array of arrays, with each array representing a section. You can use `UILocalizedIndexedCollation` (or my replacement) to do this. Here's a small `NSArray` category method I use to do this:

```
@implementation NSArray (Indexing)

- (NSArray *)indexUsingCollation:(UILocalizedIndexedCollation *)collation withSelector:(SEL)selector;
{
    NSMutableArray *indexedCollection;

    NSInteger index, sectionTitlesCount = [[collation sectionTitles] count];  
    indexedCollection = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:sectionTitlesCount];

    for (index = 0; index < sectionTitlesCount; index++) {
        NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [indexedCollection addObject:array];
        [array release];
    }

    // Segregate the data into the appropriate section
    for (id object in self) {
        NSInteger sectionNumber = [collation sectionForObject:object collationStringSelector:selector];
        [[indexedCollection objectAtIndex:sectionNumber] addObject:object];
    }

    // Now that all the data's in place, each section array needs to be sorted.
    for (index = 0; index < sectionTitlesCount; index++) {
        NSMutableArray *arrayForSection = [indexedCollection objectAtIndex:index];

        NSArray *sortedArray = [collation sortedArrayFromArray:arrayForSection collationStringSelector:selector];
        [indexedCollection replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:sortedArray];
    } 
    NSArray *immutableCollection = [indexedCollection copy];
    [indexedCollection release];

    return [immutableCollection autorelease];
}

@end
```

So, given an array of objects, for example `books` that I want to divide into sections based on their name (the `Book` class has a `name` method), I would do this:

```
NSArray *books = [self getBooks]; // etc...
UILocalizedIndexedCollation *collation = [UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation];
NSArray *indexedBooks = [books indexUsingCollation:collation withSelector:@selector(name)];
```

Comment: I just realized that the name of this category method could be improved; given that the name implies that it modifies the receiver rather than a new Array, a better name would probably be indexedArrayUsingCollation:withSelector:.

I also welcome any improvements to the above category. I'm sure it could be more efficient.